# Lie algebra homomorphism induces lie group homomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

We have this:

Theorem 1. If $H$ and $G$ are Lie groups with $H$ simply connected,
then for any Lie algebra homomorphism $\psi: h \rightarrow g$ there exists a unique
Lie group homomorphism $\phi : H \rightarrow G $ with $d\phi = \psi$.

My question is how to find example of two Lie groups $H, G$ and a Lie algebra homomorphism
$\psi: h \rightarrow g$ such that there exists no Lie group homomorphism
$\phi : H \rightarrow G $ with $d\phi = \psi$?

I know that H can't be simply connected, but I have no idea for an example and how to prove in that case that does not exist such $\phi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance, take $H=S^1$, $G=\Bbb R$, and let $\psi\colon\mathfrak h(=\Bbb R)\longrightarrow\mathfrak g(=\Bbb R)$ be the identity map. Since the only continuous group homomorphism from $S^1$ into $\Bbb R$ is the trivial homomorphism, there is no homomorphism $\phi\colon S^1\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that $\operatorname d\phi=\psi$.